# Function to insert text line by line from a file into string array passed by pointer

Tags: c, fgets, getline

I'm trying to create a function read_lines that takes a file *fp, a pointer to char** lines, and pointer to int num_lines. The function should insert each line of text into lines, and increase num_lines to however many lines the file has.

Its probably really simple but I've been trying to insert the text for several hours now.

This is what main.c would look like. Everything but read_lines is already defined and working.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    char** lines = NULL;
    int num_lines = 0;
    FILE* fp = validate_input(argc, argv);
    read_lines(fp, &lines, &num_lines);
    print_lines(lines, num_lines);
    free_lines(lines, num_lines);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

This is one of my attempts at trying to append lines, but I couldn't figure it out.

read_lines.c

```
void read_lines(FILE *fp, char ***lines, int *num_lines) {
    int i;
    int N = 0;
    char s[200];
    for (i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        while(fgets(s, 200, fp)!=NULL){N++;}
        char strings[50][200];

        rewind(fp);
        fgets(s, 200, fp);
        strcpy(lines[i],s);
    }

}
```

I'd appreciate any help at solving this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A solution (without headers and error checking for readability):

```
void read_lines(FILE *stream, char ***lines_ptr, size_t *num_lines_ptr) {
   char **lines = NULL;
   size_t num_lines = 0;
   char *line = NULL;
   size_t len = 0;
   ssize_t nread;
   while ((nread = getline(&line, &len, stream)) != -1) {
      lines = lines == NULL
         ? malloc(sizeof(char*))
         : realloc(lines, (num_lines+1)*sizeof(char*));

      lines[num_lines] = malloc(nread+1);
      memcpy(lines[num_lines], line);
      ++num_lines;
   }

   free(line);
   *lines_ptr = lines;
   *num_lines_ptr = num_lines;
}
```

The full solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// lines_ptr:     Output. Initial value ignored. To be freed by caller on success.
// num_lines_ptr: Output. Initial value ignored.
// Returns:       0 on error (errno set). 1 on success.
int read_lines(FILE *stream, char ***lines_ptr, size_t *num_lines_ptr) {
   char ***lines = NULL;
   size_t num_lines = 0;
   char *line = NULL;
   size_t len = 0;
   ssize_t nread;
   while ((nread = getline(&line, &len, stream)) != -1) {
      char **new_lines = lines == NULL
         ? malloc(sizeof(char*))
         : realloc(lines, (num_lines+1)*sizeof(char*));
      if (new_lines == NULL)
         goto error;

      lines = new_lines;

      lines[num_lines] = malloc(nread+1);
      if (lines[num_lines] == NULL)
         goto error;

      memcpy(lines[num_lines], line);
      ++num_lines;
   }

   if (ferror(stream))
      goto error;

   free(line);
   *lines_ptr = lines;
   *num_lines_ptr = num_lines;
   return 1;

error:
   for (size_t i=num_lines; i--; )
      free(lines[i]);

   free(lines);
   free(line);
   *lines_ptr = NULL;
   *num_lines_ptr = 0;
   return 0;
}
```

(You could save three lines by using the `..._ptr` vars instead of setting them at the end, but is that really worth the readability cost?)

Comment: This is about the only place you want to be a Three-star Programmer (unless you want to return `char**` or (`NULL` for failure) and assign the return back in `main()` `:)`

Comment: @David C. Rankin, Yeah, you could return the lines instead of using an argument, but I kept the OP's signature. To be honest, removing one output parameters doesn't really help if you're still left with one.

Comment: Yep, since you have the `nul_lines_ptr`, you are good to go on the number of lines filled, returning the pointer or `NULL` for success/failure instead of `0/1` just eliminates the need to pass `line_ptr` (but candidly, I have done it this way a number of times) Its the only way to go if you are filling the lines in a callback type function in, e.g. Gtk or other toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

I find fgets hard to use and more trouble than it's worth. Here is a fgetc and malloc-based approach:

```
void read_lines(FILE *fp, char ***lines, int *num_lines) {
    int c;

    size_t line = 0;
    size_t pos  = 0;
    size_t len  = 64;
    *lines = malloc(1 * sizeof(char*));
    (*lines)[0] = malloc(len);
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n') {
             (*lines)[line][pos] = '\0';
             line++;
             pos = 0;
             len = 64;
             *lines = realloc(*lines, (line+1) * sizeof(char*));
        } else {
            (*lines)[line][pos] = c;
        }
        pos++;
        if (pos >= len) {
            len *= 2;
            (*lines)[line] = realloc((*lines)[line], len);
        }
    }
    *num_lines = line+1;
}
```

I haven't checked this, so correct me if I made any mistakes. Also, in real code you would do lots of error checking here that I have omitted.

Answer (score -1):

```
assuming you have allocated enough memory to lines, following should work
if not you have to malloc/calloc() for lines[i] before doing strcpy() in every 
iteration of the loop.


void read_lines(FILE *fp, char ***lines, int *num_lines) {
       int N = 0;
       char s[200];
       while(fgets(s, 200, fp)!=NULL){
             N++;
             strcpy((*lines)[N],s);
       }
       *num_lines = N; // update pointer with value of N which is number of lines in file
}
```

Comment: What is `line[i]`? Did you mean `(*line)[i]`